# HTML container not styling child div's properly

Tags: html, css

I am trying to set the background color of my container `div` and all child `div's` within it but I can't get it to work for some reason, and I am unsure as to where I am going wrong.

When I set the `background-color` and a border on the container you can see that it is not actually "containing" any child elements.

```
#facility_container{
    text-align: center;
    padding: 2px;
    width: 100%;
    background-color: #ffffff;
}
```

Here is a [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/docg128w/) demonstrating where I am at so far.

Comment: You need to clear your floating elements, or not use float at all.

Comment: @BrianGlaz How would I clear the floating elements?

Answer (score 1):

Add `overflow: hidden` to `#facility_container`, `#facility_general_info`, `#facility_section_info`

Float makes the inner divs not expand the outer ones. Using table settings to style your page is a big no-no in HTML5.

working jsfiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/nayish/docg128w/8/

Answer (score 0):

The issue here is that, since your *#facility_info* divs are floated, they are taken out of the normal element flow, and therefore do not affect the width or height of the *#facility_container* div.

As suggested by [Jon Ducket in his book *HTML & CSS*](http://wtf.tw/ref/duckett.pdf):
Set the container div's overflow property to auto, and its width property to 100%.

```
#facility_container {
    text-align: center;
    padding: 2px;
    width: 100%;
    background-color: #ffffff;
    width: 100%;
    overflow: auto;
}
```

In this case, since *#facility_general_info* already takes up width and height, it is not necessary to set *#facility_container*'s width to 100%, but the above-mentioned property values can be used for elements that contain only floated elements.